# CSS3 :before - can you use retina imagery?

Tags: css

Is it possible to size an image placed using :before?

ie if i wanted to use a retina image in teh following contentx - how would i set the size?

```
.buy_tickets_btn:before{
        content:url(../images/buttons/pink_ticket_btn_bg.png);
```

Comment: You can always make it a background-image and simply set `content: ""; width: 200px; height: 300px; display: inline-block;`. Adjust the dimensions according to your image's dimensions. By applying `background-size: cover;` you'd make sure retina images are scaled down properly.

Comment: What is the specific reason you want to use a pseudo element instead of setting the background of the button? A retina image is just like any other image, just a higher source resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always make it a `background-image` and simply set `content: ""; width: 200px; height: 300px; display: inline-block;`.

Adjust the dimensions according to your non-retina image's dimensions.

By applying `background-size: cover;` you'd make sure retina images are scaled down properly.

```
.buy_tickets_btn:before{
  background: url(../images/buttons/pink_ticket_btn_bg.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
  content: "";
  width: 200px;  /* adjust to width of no-retina image */
  height: 300px; /* adjust to height of no-retina image */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

For the retina images to be used, just adjust the filename in the relevant media query (just a sample media query here):

```
@media screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
  .buy_tickets_btn:before{
    background-image: url(../images/buttons/pink_ticket_btn_bg_retina.png);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can, and there is not a compelling reason to use a pseudo element like `:before` or `:after`, I would set background image on your button element itself setting the `background-size` to `100%` or `cover`.

If you need to use a pseudo element you will need to position and stretch that element so it is the same size as the parent element. This is done by setting `position: relative;` on the parent and using `position: absolute;` along with setting the position properties to zero (`top: 0;`, `right: 0;`, `bottom: 0;`, `left: 0;`). Setting those properties to zero stretches an element to the boundaries of its containing element.

Below I have two examples, one using background on a normal element and one using a pseudo element.

```css
.btn,
button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
}
button {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  border: 0;
}

.bg .btn,
.bg button,
.pseudo .btn:before,
.pseudo button:before {
  background-image: url( 'http://lorempixel.com/1200/400/city/1' );
  background-size: 100%;
}

.pseudo .btn,
.pseudo button {
  position: relative;
}
.pseudo .btn:before,
.pseudo button:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h2>Background Image</h2>
<div class="bg">
  <div class="btn">Button</div>
  <button type="button">Button</button>
</div>

<h2>Before Pseudo Element Background Image</h2>
<div class="pseudo">
  <div class="btn">Button</div>
  <button type="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

I have set a width and height but this might not be required if the button is being contained by another element that is determining its width.